# Regex to replace filepaths in a string when there's more than one in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble finding a way to match multiple filepaths in a string while maintaining the rest of the string.

**EDIT:** forgot to add that the filepath might contain a dot, so edited "username" to user.name"

```
# filepath always starts with "file:///" and ends with file extension
text = """this is an example text extracted from file:///c:/users/user.name/download/temp/anecdote.pdf 
1 of 4 page and I also continue with more text from 
another path file:///c:/windows/system32/now with space in name/file (1232).html running out of text to write."""
```

I've found many answers that work, **but fails when theres more than one filepath**, also replacing the other characters in between.

```
import re
fp_pattern = r"file:\/\/\/(\w|\W){1,255}\.[\w]{3,4}"
print(re.sub(fp_pattern, "*IGOTREPLACED*", text, flags=re.MULTILINE))

>>>"this is an example text extracted from *IGOTREPLACED* running out of text to write."
```

I've also tried using a "stop when after finding a whitespace after the pattern" but I couldn't get one to work:

```
fp_pattern = r"file:\/\/\/(\w|\W){1,255}\.[\w]{3,4} ([^\s]+)"
>>> 0 matches
```

Comment: Do not use `(\w|\W)`, use `.` with `re.S` flag to match any char. Try replacing `(\w|\W){1,255}` with `.{1,255}?` and `[\w]{3,4}` with `\w{3,4}\b` or  `\w{3,4}(?!\S)`, but pass `re.S` to the `re.sub`, like `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, flags=re.S)`

Comment: Thanks, will do it in my code (but won't edit here). Could you elaborate why?

Comment: You are matching too much with `(\w|\W){1,255}` because that matches everything, *and* matches are as long as possible. That's why you get everything up to the *next* match. Add a `?` to make it match the shortest path.

Comment: @usr2564301, add a `?` where exactly?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/8kjZQK/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks, it seem the `.{1,255}?` would resolve if, but I forgot to add to the question that the filepath might contain a dot as in `users/some.name/desktop`. I edited your regex101 https://regex101.com/r/8kjZQK/3

Comment: That is why I do not think `?` will solve it and suggested a word or whitespace boundary. See https://regex101.com/r/8kjZQK/4. `(?!\S)` will only match at the end of string or if whitespace follows 3 or 4 word chars after a dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited your regex101 with a dot in the filepath string and it broke: https://regex101.com/r/8kjZQK/3 .

Comment: See the 4th version. https://regex101.com/r/8kjZQK/4. You should come up with the right boundary yourself - this is not possible to match arbitrary path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `{1,255}` is a greedy quantifier, and will match as many chars as possible, you need to add `?` after it.

However, just using a lazy `{1,255}?` quantifier won't solve the problem. You need to define where the match should end. It seems you only want to match these URLs when the extension is immediately followed with whitespace or end of string.

Hence, use

```
fp_pattern = r"file:///.{1,255}?\.\w{3,4}(?!\S)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8kjZQK/4)

The `(?!\S)` negative lookahead will fail any match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a non-whitespace char. `.{1,255}?` will match any 1 to 255 chars, as few as possible.

Use in Python as

```
re.sub(fp_pattern, "*IGOTREPLACED*", text, flags=re.S)
```

The `re.MULTILINE` (`re.M`) flag only redefines `^` and `$` anchor behavior making them match start/end of *lines* rather than the whole string. The `re.S` flag allows `.` to match any chars, including line break chars.

Please never use `(\w|\W){1,255}?`, use `.{1,255}?` with `re.S` flag to match any char, else, performance will decrease.

Answer (score -1):

You can try re.findall to find out how many time regex matches in string. Hope this helps.

```
import re
len(re.findall(pattern, string_to_search))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but it isn't what I'm needing help with. Please read carefully cheers.